# Postgres Migrate Data To New Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, postgresql

I have two Postgres databases, one `old` and one `new`.

How do I move the data from `old` to `new` while keeping the existing data that's in `new` (and of course the data that's being migrated from `old`) in tact? Also, what if I want to add mappings from old table names to new table names?

Taking both databases offline is a possibility, if truly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `--data` option to `pg_dump`.  This should produce a dump that won't drop or recreate tables or overwrite existing data.

Something like:

`pg_dump --data database_name > dump.sql`

This can be restored to the database using something like:

`psql database_name << dump.sql`

I'd be very careful using this if you have important data in "new", and I'd make sure I had a dump of the new database (with schema included, not just data) in case I messed it up.

*NOTE*: you tagged this with rails, so be aware that this approach will bypass any ActiveRecord validations you have (including validations for uniqueness, etc.

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to add mappings from old table names to new table names? Editing original question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to load your original dump in a text editor and edit the table names by hand.  It depends on how much mapping of column names you need to do -- at some point, you'll want to actually use a script to transfer the data.